# image proccessing further optimization

Tags: c, image, image-processing, optimization

I'm new to optimization and was given a task to optimize a function that processes an image as much as possible. it takes an image, blurs it and then saves the blurred image, and then continues and sharpens the image, and saves also the sharpened image.

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char red;
   unsigned char green;
   unsigned char blue;
} pixel;

// I delete the other struct because we can do the same operations with     use of only addresses

//use macro instead of function is more efficient
#define calculateIndex(i, j, n) ((i)*(n)+(j))


// I combine all the functions in one because it is time consuming
void myfunction(Image *image, char* srcImgpName, char* blurRsltImgName,    char* sharpRsltImgName) {
    // use variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
    register int i,j, ii, jj, sum_red, sum_green, sum_blue; 
    //using local variable is much more efficient than using pointer to   pixels from the original image,and updat its value in each iteration
    pixel current_pixel , p;

    //dst will point on the first pixel in the image
    pixel* dst = (pixel*)image->data;

    int squareN = n*n;
    //instead of multiply by 3 - I used shift 
    register int sizeToAllocate = ((squareN)<<1)+(squareN); // use variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
    pixel* src = malloc(sizeToAllocate);

    register int index;

    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);

    ///////////////////////////////////////// first step : smooth //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    /**the smooth blur is step that apply the blur-kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more smooth.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
*because the matrix is full of 1 , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable.
*/

    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    index = calculateIndex(1, 1, n);
    for (i = 1 ; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n - 1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            for(ii = i-1; ii <= i+1; ++ii) {
                for(jj =j-1; jj <= j+1; ++jj) {
                    //take care of the [ii,jj] pixel in the matrix
                    //calculate the adrees of the current pixel
                    pixel p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];       
                    //sum the colors' values of the neighbors of the current pixel
                    sum_red += p.red;
                    sum_green +=  p.green;
                    sum_blue += p.blue;
                }
            }
            //calculate the avarage of the colors' values around the current pixel - as written in the instructions
            sum_red = (((sum_red) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_green = (((sum_green) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_blue = (((sum_blue) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient

            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;
            dst[index++] = current_pixel;
        }
    }
    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, blurRsltImgName);
    
    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);


    ///////////////////////////////////////// second step : sharp //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    /** I want to sharp the smooth image . In this step I apply the sharpen kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more sharp.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [-1, -1, -1]
* [-1, 9, -1]
* [-1, -1, -1]
*because the matrix is full of (-1) , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable. I operato like that : insted of multiply in (-1) in the end of the step , I define counter initializes with zero , and
*substruct all te colors' values from it. the result is actually the same as multiply by (-1), in more efficient way.
*/

    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    for (i = 1 ; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n-1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            // Do central pixel first
            p=src[calculateIndex(i,j,n)];
            sum_red   = 10*p.red;
            sum_green = 10*p.green;
            sum_blue  = 10*p.blue;

            for(ii =i-1; ii <= i + 1; ++ii) {
                for(jj = j-1; jj <= j + 1; ++jj) {
                    p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];
                    //operate according to the instructions
                    sum_red -= p.red;
                    sum_green -= p.green;
                    sum_blue -= p.blue;
                }
            }

            //each pixel's colors' values must match the range [0,255] - I used the idea from the original code

            //the red value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_red < 0) {
                sum_red = 0;
            } else if (sum_red > 255 ) {
                sum_red = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;


            //the green value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_green < 0) {
            sum_green = 0;
            } else if (sum_green > 255 ) {
            sum_green = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;


            //the blue value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_blue < 0) {
                sum_blue = 0;
            } else if (sum_blue > 255 ) {
                sum_blue = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;


            // put the updated pixel in [i,j] in the image
            dst[calculateIndex(i, j, n)] = current_pixel;
        }
    }

    //free the allocated space to prevent memory leaks
    free(src);

    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, sharpRsltImgName);
}
```

I wanted to ask about the if statements, is there anything better that can replace those? And also more generally speaking can anyone spot an optimization mistakes here, or can offer his inputs?

Thanks a lot!

---

updated code:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char red;
   unsigned char green;
   unsigned char blue;
} pixel;

// I delete the other struct because we can do the same operations with use of only addresses

//use macro instead of function is more efficient
#define calculateIndex(i, j, n) ((i)*(n)+(j))


// I combine all the functions in one because it is time consuming
void myfunction(Image *image, char* srcImgpName, char* blurRsltImgName, char* sharpRsltImgName) {
    // use variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
register int i,j, ii, jj, sum_red, sum_green, sum_blue; 
    //using local variable is much more efficient than using pointer to pixels from the original image,and updat its value in each iteration
    pixel current_pixel , p;

    //dst will point on the first pixel in the image
    pixel* dst = (pixel*)image->data;

    int squareN = n*n;
    //instead of multiply by 3 - I used shift 
    register int sizeToAllocate = ((squareN)<<1)+(squareN); // use variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
    pixel* src = malloc(sizeToAllocate);

    register int index;

    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);

    ///////////////////////////////////////// first step : smooth //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    /**the smooth blur is step that apply the blur-kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more smooth.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
*because the matrix is full of 1 , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable.
*/

    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    index = calculateIndex(1, 1, n);
    for (i = 1 ; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n - 1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            for(ii = i-1; ii <= i+1; ++ii) {
                for(jj =j-1; jj <= j+1; ++jj) {
                    //take care of the [ii,jj] pixel in the matrix
                    //calculate the adrees of the current pixel
                    pixel p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];       
                    //sum the colors' values of the neighbors of the current pixel
                    sum_red += p.red;
                    sum_green +=  p.green;
                    sum_blue += p.blue;
                }
            }
            //calculate the avarage of the colors' values around the current pixel - as written in the instructions
            sum_red = (((sum_red) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_green = (((sum_green) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_blue = (((sum_blue) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient

            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;
            dst[index++] = current_pixel;
        }
        index += 2;
    }
    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, blurRsltImgName);
    
    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);


    ///////////////////////////////////////// second step : sharp //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    /** I want to sharp the smooth image . In this step I apply the sharpen kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more sharp.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [-1, -1, -1]
* [-1, 9, -1]
* [-1, -1, -1]
*because the matrix is full of (-1) , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable. I operato like that : insted of multiply in (-1) in the end of the step , I define counter initializes with zero , and
*substruct all te colors' values from it. the result is actually the same as multiply by (-1), in more efficient way.
*/

    index = calculateIndex(1,1,n);
    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    for (i = 1 ; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n-1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            // Do central pixel first
            p=src[index];
            sum_red   = 10*p.red;
            sum_green = 10*p.green;
            sum_blue  = 10*p.blue;

            for(ii =i-1; ii <= i + 1; ++ii) {
                for(jj = j-1; jj <= j + 1; ++jj) {
                    p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];
                    //operate according to the instructions
                    sum_red -= p.red;
                    sum_green -= p.green;
                    sum_blue -= p.blue;
                }
                index += 2;
            }

            //each pixel's colors' values must match the range [0,255] - I used the idea from the original code

            //the red value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_red < 0) {
                sum_red = 0;
            } else if (sum_red > 255 ) {
                sum_red = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;


            //the green value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_green < 0) {
                sum_green = 0;
            } else if (sum_green > 255 ) {
                sum_green = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;


            //the blue value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_blue < 0) {
                sum_blue = 0;
            } else if (sum_blue > 255 ) {
                sum_blue = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;


            // put the updated pixel in [i,j] in the image
            dst[calculateIndex(i, j, n)] = current_pixel;
        }
    }

    //free the allocated space to prevent memory leaks
    free(src);

    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, sharpRsltImgName);
}
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------updated code:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char red;
   unsigned char green;
   unsigned char blue;
} pixel;

// I delete the other struct because we can do the same operations with use of only addresses

//use macro instead of function is more efficient
#define calculateIndex(i, j, n) ((i)*(n)+(j))


// I combine all the functions in one because it is time consuming
void myfunction(Image *image, char* srcImgpName, char* blurRsltImgName, char* sharpRsltImgName) {
    // use variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
    register int i,j, ii, jj, sum_red, sum_green, sum_blue; 
    //using local variable is much more efficient than using pointer to pixels from the original image,and updat its value in each iteration
    pixel current_pixel , p;

    //dst will point on the first pixel in the image
    pixel* dst = (pixel*)image->data;

    int squareN = n*n;
    //instead of multiply by 3 - I used shift 
    register int sizeToAllocate = ((squareN)<<1)+(squareN); // use    variable from type 'register int' is much more efficient from 'int'
    pixel* src = malloc(sizeToAllocate);

    register int index;

    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);

    ///////////////////////////////////////// first step : smooth //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    /**the smooth blur is step that apply the blur-kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more smooth.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
* [1, 1, 1]
*because the matrix is full of 1 , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable.
*/

    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    index = n + 1;
    for (i = 1 ; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n - 1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            for(ii = i-1; ii <= i+1; ++ii) {
                for(jj =j-1; jj <= j+1; ++jj) {
                    //take care of the [ii,jj] pixel in the matrix
                    //calculate the adrees of the current pixel
                    pixel p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];       
                    //sum the colors' values of the neighbors of the current pixel
                    sum_red += p.red;
                    sum_green +=  p.green;
                    sum_blue += p.blue;
                }
            }
            //calculate the avarage of the colors' values around the current pixel - as written in the instructions
            sum_red = (((sum_red) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_green = (((sum_green) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient
            sum_blue = (((sum_blue) * 0xE38F) >> 19);//instead of dividing by 9 - I used shift because it is more efficient

            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;
            dst[index++] = current_pixel;
        }
        index += 2;
    }
    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, blurRsltImgName);
    
    //memcpy replace the old functions that converts chars to pixels or pixels to chars. it is very efficient and build-in in c libraries
    memcpy(src, dst, sizeToAllocate);


    ///////////////////////////////////////// second step : sharp //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    /** I want to sharp the smooth image . In this step I apply the sharpen kernel (matrix of ints) over each pixel in the bouns - and make the image more sharp.
*this function was originally used this matrix :
* [-1, -1, -1]
* [-1, 9, -1]
* [-1, -1, -1]
*because the matrix is full of (-1) , we don't really need it - the access to the matrix is very expensive . instead of the matrix I used 
*primitive variable. I operate like that : instead of multiply in (-1) in the end of the step , I define counter initializes with zero , and
*substruct all te colors' values from it. the result is actually the same as multiply by (-1), in more efficient way.
*/

    index = calculateIndex(1,1,n);
    //the loops are starting with 1 and not with 0 because we need to check only the pixels with 8 neighbors around them
    for (i = 1 ; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (j =  1 ; j < n-1 ; ++j) {
            // I used this variables as counters to the colors' values around a specific pixel
            sum_red = 0;
            sum_green = 0;
            sum_blue = 0;

            // Do central pixel first
            p=src[index];
            sum_red   = 10*p.red;
            sum_green = 10*p.green;
            sum_blue  = 10*p.blue;

            for(ii =i-1; ii <= i + 1; ++ii) {
                for(jj = j-1; jj <= j + 1; ++jj) {
                    p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];
                    //operate according to the instructions
                    sum_red -= p.red;
                    sum_green -= p.green;
                    sum_blue -= p.blue;
                }
            }

            //each pixel's colors' values must match the range [0,255] - I used the idea from the original code

            //the red value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_red < 0) {
                sum_red = 0;
            } else if (sum_red > 255 ) {
                sum_red = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.red = (unsigned char)sum_red;


            //the green value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_green < 0) {
                sum_green = 0;
            } else if (sum_green > 255 ) {
                sum_green = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned char)sum_green;


            //the blue value must be in the range [0,255]
            if (sum_blue < 0) {
                sum_blue = 0;
            } else if (sum_blue > 255 ) {
                sum_blue = 255;
            }
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned char)sum_blue;


            // put the updated pixel in [i,j] in the image
            dst[calculateIndex(i, j, n)] = current_pixel;
        }
        index += 2;
    }

    //free the allocated space to prevent memory leaks
    free(src);

    // write result image to file
    writeBMP(image, srcImgpName, sharpRsltImgName);
}
```

Comment: Blur filters like the Gaussian Blur filter are separable. That's a very important optimization. Also, you can perform some operations in parallel. In fact, the "*shift*" is insignificant as an optimization in this case.

Comment: My advice, don't bother optimizing anything until after you do what @IharobAlAsimi suggested re: separable filters.  Then you'll want to measure the performance of your code.

Comment: If you have working code, and you're just wanting people to review it to try to improve it, you should be asking on [codereview.se] instead; that's exactly the reason it was created. This site is for questions about problems you're having with code, not about suggestions for improvement or optimization.

Comment: Also, depending on the size of the image you can use the Fast Fourier Transform to perform convolution, since it is just a point to point multiplication instead of a summation. But if the image is not large enough, then a smaller kernel and a normal convolution could be faster, there is a trade off in the cost of computing the FFT of the kernel + image & convolution, and the cost of a direct convolution.

Comment: The `ifs` are inside four nested loops. Even if you optimized the hell out of them, you're still stuck with a slow algorithm. Re-think the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Some general optimization guidelines:

1. If you're running on x86, compile as a 64-bit binary.  x86 is really a register-starved CPU.  In 32-bit mode you pretty much have only 5 or 6 32-bit general-purpose registers available, and you only get "all" 6 if you compile with optimizations like `-fomit-frame-pointer` on GCC.  In 64-bit mode you'll have 13 or 14 64-bit general-purpose registers.
2. Get a good compiler and use the highest possible general optimization level.
3. Profile! Profile! Profile!  Actually profile your code so actually know where the performance bottlenecks are.  Any guesses about the location of any performance bottlenecks are likely wrong.
4. Once you find your bottlenecks, examine the actual instructions the compiler produces and look at the bottleneck areas, just to see what's happening.  Perhaps the bottleneck is where the compiler had to do a lot of [register spilling and filling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation#Spilling) because of register pressure.  This can be really helpful if you can profile down to the instruction level.
5. Use the insights from the profiling and examination of the generated instructions to improve your code and compile arguments.  For example, if you're seeing a lot of register spilling and filling, you need to reduce register pressure, perhaps by manually coalescing loops or disabling prefetching with a compiler option.
6. Experiment with different page size options.  If a single row of pixels is a significant fraction of a page size, reaching into other rows is more likely to reach into another page and result in a [TLB miss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#TLB-miss_handling).  Using larger memory pages may significantly reduce this.

Some specific ideas for your code:

1. Use only one outer loop.  You'll have to experiment to find the fastest way to handle your "extra" edge pixels.  The fastest way might be to not do anything special, roll right over them like "normal" pixels, and just ignore the values in them later.
2. Manually unroll the two inner loops - you're only doing 9 pixels.
3. Don't use `calculateIndex()` - use the *address* of the current pixel and find the other pixels simply by subtracting or adding the proper value from the current pixel address.  For example, the address of the upper-left pixel in your inner loops would be something like `currentPixelAddress - n - 1`.

Those would convert your four-deep nested loops into a single loop with very little index calculations needed.

Comment: Good advice. Being a bit more specific on 2), you could maybe suggest something like using the following switches on the compiler `-march=native -O3`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, the OP didn't specify the compiler in use so I didn't want to get into that.

Comment: Fair enough, it's your answer :-) I have often found that some OPs and beginners don't understand the significance of what more experienced folks are suggesting so they ignore that piece of advice - I remember wishing people had given concrete examples of all the stuff they knew when I was starting out all those years ago. We casually say *"profile your code"* but don't mention **how** to compile for, or run profiling. We say *"symlink the latest version of XYZ"* but don't say **how** to symlink or **where** to download it from.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas - untested.

---

You have `if(ii==i && jj=j)` to test for the central pixel in your sharpening loop which you do 9x for every pixel. I think it would be faster to remove that `if` and do exactly the same for every pixel but then make a correction, outside the loop by adding 10x the central pixel.

```
    // Do central pixel first
    p=src[calculateIndex(i,j,n)];
    sum_red   = 10*p.red;
    sum_green = 10*p.green;
    sum_blue  = 10*p.blue;

    for(ii =i-1; ii <= i + 1; ++ii) {
        for(jj = j-1; jj <= j + 1; ++jj) {
            p = src[calculateIndex(ii, jj, n)];
            //operate according to the instructions
            sum_red -= p.red;
            sum_green -= p.green;
            sum_blue -= p.blue;
        }
    }
```

---

Where you do `dst[calculateIndex(i, j, n)] = current_pixel;`, you can probably calculate the index once before the loop at the start and then just increment the pointer with each write inside the loop - assuming your arrays are contiguous and unpadded.

```
index=calculateIndex(1,1,n)
for (i = 1 ; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    for (j =  1 ; j < n - 1 ; ++j) {
        ...
        dst[index++] = current_pixel;
    }
    index+=2; // skip over last pixel of this line and first pixel of next line
}
```

---

As you move your 3x3 window of 9 pixels across the image, you could *"remember"* the left-most column of 3 pixels from the previous position, then instead of 9 additions for each pixel, you would do a single subtraction for the left-most column leaving the window and 3 additions for the new column entering the window on the right side, i.e. 4 calculations instead of 9.

Comment: hi Mark, can you please elaborate?
I'm not sure I understood how to implement your ideas.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to implement your first suggestion and it turned my image to all white, any idea why?

Comment: Try running under your debugger and put a breakpoint in where the modified code starts and step through it.

Comment: Got it. I'm now trying to remove the index calculation...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, in your second suggestion, I did not understand how can we use the calcIndex before the loops where i and j are not initialized?
Also just for the sake of trying, I tried to do that and got an "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error...

Comment: It's the first pixel, so `i` and `j` are `1` since you don't process the outer edges of your image. I have updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Normally, btw, you would divide your smoothed image by the sum of the elements in the convolution matrix, i.e. divide the `sum_red`, `sum_green`, `sum_blue` by 9 at the end else your smoothed image will be brighter than the original.

Comment: When you have got all the ideas implemented, consider starting 4 threads in parallel and letting them start processing at row 0, row N/4, row N/2, row 3*N/4... ;-)

Comment: I fixed the bug. and my image got distorted trying to implement your second suggestion...
Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks man. It worked, but I'm still having trouble with the sharpening of the image, it turns it to white again... I will update the code here so you can review it.

Comment: Leave the original code for other folks to see. Just go to the bottom of your question and add `---` (a horizontal rule) and a new line and then paste the updated code.

Comment: In the updated code I got a segmentation fault for some reason, when trying to implement your second suggestion. can you please help?

Comment: You have put `index+=2` far too soon. It should be two lines above `free(src)`

Comment: I've uploaded to the bottom of the page the updated code. Thanks Mark!

Comment: It's working. just trying to figure out how to do the same for the internal macro...